# Ec2 spot pricing graph stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A long time ago, there was the most useful spot price comparison graph that I have ever used, but it **stopped working, as far as I know, because the creator ran out of time** to maintain it. The website is still active [ec2price.com](https://ec2price.com/) and the code is on Github. Does anyone know if anyone has replicated this? or any way to do it myself? As I said it was really useful to decide which spot instance to choose.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this information in the EC2 console by browsing to *Spot Requests* and selecting the *Pricing History* button.

If you want to select the cheapest ec2 instance type automatically you can create a *spot fleet request*; select all the instance types you might want to use and an allocation strategy of *lowestPrice*. Deploy this to a VPC with a subnet in all availability zones in your region to get the lowest price possible.

Comment: yep, I know about that part of the console but it is by far less clear than this website was.

Answer (score 2):

Besides codes, somebody must pay to maintain server that polling the information.

Check out [How Spot Fleet Works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html). Spot fleet is way better than price monitoring. You can make request base on pricing for a fleet of instance type than limit yourself to specific instance type.  You can kick start instances from a large fleet base on maximum instance price or vCPU price.

If you are using a SPOT ready batch application, after submit your bidding for fleet of different instance type and set the maximum per vCPU price, Spotfleet will automatically launch available instance with the best price. So you don't need to compete with limited popular instance(for example, c4.* SPOT instance is scarce for most region).

This is a win-win for both AWS and customer, as AWS able to spread the usage to underutilized instance type. IMHO, There is no point of keep raising the bid for particular type if those instance exhausted, while there is still many idle AWS instances in alternate zone that are not fully utilised for grab.